# Cypress wait for all ajax requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I'm testing a heavy page with cypress, and I need to wait until there are no active XHR requests, I have tried to use Cypress.$.active === 0, but this is always true even when there are active ones.
What should I do?

Comment: I believe Cypress only has built-in support to wait for stubbed XHR requests. There's no built-in support wait for non-stubbed requests to finish. Would it be possible to simply wait for a certain button to appear? In addition, what are you trying to test?

Comment: I have no way to know how many requests I'm waiting for, that's why I need to find a function outside cypress to do it. And I'm trying to not rely on animations only, because my tests are not written for a specific element

Answer (score 1):

In Cypress you can wait on intercepted requests.
You do not have to stub the response for these requests, by default they will still call their original destination.

```
cy.intercept('/**').as('ajax-requests');

...actions that trigger AJAX requests...

cy.wait('@ajax-requests');
```

Comment: You mean cy.wait('@ajax-requests');